# How to get Intellisense working with custom python enum which uses a classproperty decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, decorator, docstring

I am trying to implement enums in python in such a way that I can use docstrings nicely.

Basically this is what I am doing/trying to do (full runable code will be at the bottom because of its length):

```py
class Animals(EnumBase):
    _dog = 'Dog'
    _cat = 'Cat'

    @classproperty
    def dog(cls):
        """
        A four legged creature that loves humans too much.
        """
        return cls._dog

    @classproperty
    def cat(cls):
        """
        Rules over humans.
        """
        return cls._cat

print(Animals.dog) # Outputs 'Dog' so programmatically works perfect
```

My code technically works fine however VS Code Intellisense cannot read the docstrings for the enums. For example when I hover over the `dog` in `print(Animals.dog)` it won't output its docstring. I assume this is because of the `classproperty` decorator but I don't know of a better way to do it (unless I switch to classmethods but I wanted to avoid the *unneeded* parathesis).

Anyone have a better way I can accomplish this, or can I not trick Intellisense into reading my docstrings?

Full runnable code is below. Note there is a lot of other functionality that is unrelated to the issue at hand (basically code that allows me to treat child classes as iterables).

```py
class classproperty(property):
    """
    Class method property decorator. (Used via @classproperty)
    A @classmethod allows us to call stuff from classes like:
    Foo.bar()
    A @property allows us to call functions like:
    Foo().bar
    But we want enum functionality with doc strings like:
    Foo.bar
    Thus the usecase of this decorator.
    """
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        """
        Redefining get.
        """
        return classmethod(self.fget).__get__(None, owner)()

class _MetaEnum(type):
    """
    Meta class needed to overload the __contains__ method for
    EnumBase.
    """
    def __contains__(cls, val):
        """
        Opertator overload for the `in` operator at a class level.
        Will return true if `x` is one of the enum values
        stored in the child class of the base class.
        """
        return val in cls._get_contents()

    def __str__(cls):
        """
        String operator overload.
        """
        return ', '.join(str(x) for x in cls._get_contents())

    def __iter__(cls):
        """
        Returns a generator for all elements in a class.
        """
        return (x for x in cls._get_contents())

class EnumBase(metaclass=_MetaEnum):
    """
    An enum base class that can be inherited by Enum classses.
    Allows the `in` operation to be perform as well as auto str formatting.
    Example:
    class Foo(EnumBase):
        a = 2
        b = 3
        c = 4
    print(2 in Foo) # True
    print(Foo) # 2, 3, 4
    """
    @classmethod
    def _get_contents(cls):
        """
        Returns a set of all different enum values.
        """
        # Get all class attributes that are not methods
        attributes = inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda a: not inspect.isroutiane(a))

        # Turn all attributes that aren't private (such as __dict__) to a set
        # and return it.
        return {a[1] for a in attributes if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))}

class Animals(EnumBase):
    _dog = 'Dog'
    _cat = 'Cat'

    @classproperty
    def dog(cls):
        """
        A four legged creature that loves humans too much.
        """
        return cls._dog

    @classproperty
    def cat(cls):
        """
        Rules over humans.
        """
        return cls._cat
```

Comment: Python has an actual `Enum` since version 3.4.  Have you tried using that with IntelliSense?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't trick the IntelliSense engine into recognizing your decorator as converting a method into a descriptor.

Comment: That was my guess but I was hoping I was wrong. I tried a whole bunch of other stuff including trying to change how I did the metaclass but even when I got the `__doc__` and `__name__` to populate correctly IntelliSense failed... Other than IntelliSense everything works as expected. Thanks for confirming it at least. I will leave it un-answered just in case someone finds a loop hole.